# Restore failed iphone 5 from iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, itunes, restore

I've just got iphone 5 and I wanted to restore it with my iPhone 3G information (mainly SMS). I try to restore it with iTunes by clicking the backup I had from my iPhone 3G but it says gives me an error message:

> Restore failed.

How can I restore my data onto my iPhone 5?

Comment: Did you have the iPhone 3GS or just the 3G?

Comment: IT's just the iPhone 3G

Comment: Can anyone help me please? How can I restore the SMS to my iPhone 5 from my iPhone 3G?

Comment: That you can't restore from an iPhone 3G (older) to iPhone 5 (newer) seems a little odd. I recommend that you perform another backup of your iPhone 3G information, and then attempt to restore that backup onto your new iPhone. As you do this, edit your post to document *every* single step of the way clearly. Then take a screenshot of the error message and include that (upload it somewhere such as Dropbox and link). You could also try http://www.backuptrans.com/iphone-sms-backup-restore.html if that doesn't work. *Either way, ping me with @bassplayer7 when you do more.*